# how to make punctuation a separate item when using split()

Tags: python, list, split

I'm writing a program that compresses text by replicating it with a sequence of numbers - but I don't know how to get the program to recognise punctuation as a separate item in the list.

eg, in this sentence with a comma, the comma means that the words `'comma,'` and `'comma'` are different when using `split()`. I want to have `'comma' ',' 'comma'` instead.

I don't want to get rid of the punctuation - i want it as a separate item in a list

Comment: Just [remove the punctuation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/265960/best-way-to-strip-punctuation-from-a-string-in-python) before you split maybe?

Comment: @cricket_007 But they want to keep the punctuation in the post-split list

Comment: What would you do with hyphenated words?

Comment: Could you put example of what you want exacly?

Answer (score 3):

You can use `re.split` like this:

```
>>> re.split('([{}])'.format(re.escape(string.punctuation)), "comma,comma")
['comma', ',', 'comma']
```

Comment: Its kind of fortuitous that the backslash character in `string.punctuation` immediately precedes `']'`, that `'^'` isn't at the beginning of the character set, that `'[,-.]'` defines a character range which includes a literal hyphen, and etc. So this ends up handling everything properly except for backslashes--although I doubt it matters in practice (who uses backslashes in normal text?). If splitting on backslashes do matter, `re.escape(string.punctuation)` will fix this.